# Rendering and displaying math equations and formulas in C# .NET desktop application

Tags: c#, .net, rendering, desktop-application, mathjax

My goal is to render and display mathematical equations, the source written in LaTeX format, within the C# desktop application.

What are the capable templates, libraries, packages, or methods specifically tailored for rendering LaTeX equations in a C# desktop application project? I'm looking for concrete solutions and code examples to achieve this functionality.

If you have successfully integrated LaTeX equation rendering into a C# GUI application, please share your experience and provide guidance on the steps and libraries used. I appreciate any practical insights to help me implement this feature.

Added details on the app: I would like to create a program which includes a collection of formulas for a certain topic, say physics. For HTML/JavaScript there is already MathJax link which makes it easy to incorporate formulas in html documents. Here you just write LaTeX (or LaTeX alike) code and MathJax renders it to great looking formulas.

I want the app to be cross platform, this rules out Winforms and WPF.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on the expected features a bit more? That might help someone helping you. To me LaTeX feels a bit like an alien concept in the .Net world so for me it sounds feasible if you have a LaText toolchain somewhere (non .Net) to create besides the Latex Documents also an image of that. Sounds lets say suboptimal but maybe good enough as you haven't told much about expectations in your question.

Comment: What kind of desktop app you envision would also presumably helpful. Winforms, WPF or even an Electron App are options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one option which seems promising. There is a project XAML-Math at https://github.com/ForNeVeR/xaml-math which enables Math rendering in XAML applications WPF and Avalonia.

Since I need to go cross-platform I'll go with Avalonia https://avaloniaui.net/.

Michael